# Range of GraphicString mentioned in ASN.1 standard

Tags: asn.1

What is the range of GraphicString which is mentioned in X.208?
Can it be maximum upto 255 character or can it be extended to more than 255?
Here asking range means what can be maximum length of string this data type can accomodate?

Comment: IMO GraphicString does not have length restriction in general.

Answer (score 0):

Character strings have unlimited length unless you constrain them with a SIZE constraint.